# How can I deserialize integer number to int, not to long?

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I'm using Json.NET to deserialize requests on the server-side.

There is something like

```
public object[] Values
```

I need to put in values like `30.0`, `27`, `54.002`, and they need to be `double`'s and `int`'s.

Json.NET has a deserialization property called *FloatParseHandling*, but there is no option like *IntParseHandling*. So the question is **how can I deserialize integers to `int`?**

Answer (score 12):

Your best bet is to deserialize into a typed model where the model *expresses* that `Values` is an `int` / `int[]` / etc. In the case of something that *has* to be `object` / `object[]` (presumably because the type is not well-known in advance, or it is an array of heterogeneous items), then it is not unreasonable for JSON.NET to default to `long`, since that will cause the least confusion when there are a mixture of big and small values in the array. Besides which, it has no way of knowing what the value was on the way in (`3L` (a `long`), when serialized in JSON, looks identical to `3` (an `int`)). You could simply post-process `Values` and look for any that are `long` and in the `int` range:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < Values.Length ; i++)
{
    if(Values[i] is long)
    {
        long l = (long)Values[i];
        if(l >= int.MinValue && l <= int.MaxValue) Values[i] = (int)l;
    }
}
```