# how to control variant types when deserializing json string into variant arrays of variants

Tags: c#, com, vb6, json.net, com-interop

i have c# com interop that deserialize json string into variant of array of variants   `object(10,1)`

i am using  the following code:

```
 var res =  (vbobj.ObjValue as JArray).ToObject<dynamic[,]>();
```

the problem is that all my numeric values from json getting VT_I8  upon return to VB6 calling module instead of VT_I4 and VB6 understandably throws an automation error.

as a work around I loop through each element i got from json deserializer and recreate array while converting every numeric value to Int32

How can i control the type of variants in more elegant way?

thank you
mark

Comment: Do [How do I change the default Type for Numeric deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8297541/344280) and/or [How can I deserialize integer number to int, not to long?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17918686/344280) answer your question?